# Or loop doing the opposite of what I want

Tags: vba

I'm trying to get an OR loop to work in VBA but instead of avoiding cells that have the letters in them, it's making the whole array "-". Even if I put in numbers or words it replaces the whole array with a dash.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim l As Double, c As Double

For l = 14 To 18
    For c = 10 To 12


    If Cells(l, c).Value <> "W" Or _
    Cells(l, c).Value <> "w" Or _
    Cells(l, c).Value <> "X" Or _
    Cells(l, c).Value <> "x" Or _
    Cells(l, c).Value <> "Y" Or _
    Cells(l, c).Value <> "y" Or _
    Cells(l, c).Value <> "Z" Or _
    Cells(l, c).Value <> "z" Then
    Cells(l, c).Value = "-"
    End If

    Next c
Next l

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you mean to use And?

Comment: Lookup "DeMorgan's Laws". (Here's the Wikipedia article, though it's a bit opaque: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

Answer (score 2):

You need to AND the conditions together.

```
If Cells(l, c).Value <> "W" And _
    Cells(l, c).Value <> "w" And _
    Cells(l, c).Value <> "X" And _
    Cells(l, c).Value <> "x" And _
    Cells(l, c).Value <> "Y" And _
    Cells(l, c).Value <> "y" And _
    Cells(l, c).Value <> "Z" And _
    Cells(l, c).Value <> "z" Then
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler way to change any cell that isn't w-Z to "-":

```
If Cells(l, c).Value Like "[!w-zW-Z]" Then
    Cells(l, c).Value = "-"
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Another efficient alternative:

```
Select Case UCase$(Cells(l, c))
    Case "W" To "Z"
        Cells(l, c).value = "-"
End Select
```